# PHP keep radio box checked after submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I use radio button with JS, HTML and PHP. When you select a radio button, you will be shown a certain content. Now I want to keep the radio button selected after submitting the form. I managed to keep the selected option, but the specific fields are not displayed.

```
    <input type="radio" name="DrCheck" id="dreptunghi" onclick="DreptunghiFunction()" <?php if(isset($_POST['DrCheck'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /><?= _DREPTUNGHI ?>
<input type="radio" name="CercCheck" id="cerc" onclick="CercFunction()" <?php if(isset($_POST['CercCheck'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /><?= _CERC ?>
<input type="radio" name="ElipsaCheck" id="elipsa" onclick="ElipsaFunction()" <?php if(isset($_POST['ElipsaCheck'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> /> <?= _ELIPSA ?>
```

Comment: you want to keep selected first one or last selected one ?

Answer (score 0):

it will be more clear if you will not use php in html for this problem, use javascript

you may try send form by ajax, jquery example:

```
$("#dreptunghi").submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

var form = $(this);
var url = form.attr('action');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data); // show response from the php script.
    }
});
});
```